# Como procurar elemento em ListBox?

Tags: delphi

Preciso procurar palavras parcialmente dentro de um `Listbox`, exemplo: um dos elementos do `Listbox` tem a palavra *Cachorro*, se eu digitar *cach* (em um edit por exemplo) ele procura e seleciona todas as palavras que iniciar com essas letras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já resolvi pessoal pra quem precisar, segue o código completo:

```
var
S : Array[0..255] of Char; 
begin
StrPCopy(S, Edit2.Text);
with ListBox1 do
ItemIndex := Perform(LB_SELECTSTRING, 0, LongInt(@S));
end;
```