# Focar item no Listbox com Delphi

Tags: delphi

O código a seguir funciona apenas se digitar a string completa, gostaria de modificar o código para também focar no listbox quando parte do texto for digitado estilo autocomplete

```
procedure Tform1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
i: Integer;
begin
i := ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(Edit1.Text);
if i>= 0 then
begin
ListBox1.ItemIndex:= ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(Edit1.Text);
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você precisa percorrer a lista em um laço de repetição e verificar item a item, pois não tem método para busca parcial na propriedade Items do TListBox. Exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Pos(Edit1.Text, ListBox1.Items[i]) > 0 then
    begin
      ListBox1.ItemIndex := i;
      break; //pra evitar que o resto da lista seja percorrido, dando foco no primeiro item encontrado
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Boa noite.. Penso do mesmo modo que o JMSlasher :)

Comment: vi uma resposta interessante sobre isso em outro post, não testei, mas parece usar API do Windows: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13929/como-procurar-elemento-em-listbox?rq=1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13929/como-procurar-elemento-em-listbox?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Para o que pretende talvez falte apenas o uso da funçao LeftStr. Algo como:

```
uses strutils;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  txtLen:integer;
begin
  //Guardar tamanho de string digitada
  txtLen:=Length(Edit1.Text);
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
     if length(ListBox1.Items[i])>=txtLen then
        if LeftStr(ListBox1.Items[i],txtLen) = Edit1.Text then
        begin
           ListBox1.ItemIndex := i;
           break;       
        end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte

```
uses System.StrUtils,
...
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ListBox1.Items do
    begin
      Add('Good morning!');
      Add('Hi, welcome to StackOverflow');
      Add('Foo Bar');
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
Var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to ListBox1.Count-1 do
    begin
      if ContainsText(ListBox1.Items[I], Edit1.Text) then
        begin
          ListBox1.ItemIndex:= I;
          Break;
        end
          else
            ListBox1.ItemIndex:= -1;
    end;
end;
```